# WPF Combox using Itemteplate with multiple sources

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I am trying to make WPF Combobox using ItemTemplate. My idea is to create items in combobox like in this tutorial https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/, but slightly different. I have 2 Lists, which I want to use as source. A List containing colors for Rectangles = colorList, and a list containing strings for TextBlocks = classesList

```
List<System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush> colorList = new List<System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush>
List<string> classesList = new List<string>


    <ComboBox Name="cmbClasses" ItemsSource=" ??? " SelectionChanged="cmbClasses_SelectionChanged"  Margin="10" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Rectangle Name="rectSelectedClassColor" Fill=" ??? " Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
                    <TextTextBlock Name="cboxSelectedClass" Text=" ??? " MinWidth="50" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Is it possible? How? Thank you.

Comment: Why are these two lists if you want the two properties in each item? Why aren't the two things you're interested in each a property of a class. You can then bind one list or observablecollection of this new class. Which presumably exposes a brush property (a solidcolorbrush using your colour) and a string property. ( Or you could make the name of your colour a string and use a converter in the view to build a solidcolorbrush. )

Comment: ASh, it was just a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: Andy, I can use any collection, those lists are just example of source data, I can put my data in any collection, or I can create new class for it, i am limited with nothing, but I know what solution is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a new class with a string and Solid color brush as properties

```
public class NewClass
{
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public SolidColorBrush Brush {get;set;}
}
```

Then should make an ObservableCollection of this class and Bind it to your combobox.

```
ObservableCollection<NewClass> Source = new ObservableCollection<NewClass>();
```

XAML could look like this.

```
<ComboBox ItemSource = "{Binding Source}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel>
       <Rectangle Fill = "{Binding Brush}"/>
       <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Name}"/>
     </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```